# Does the placement of the current arrow before or after a resistor make a difference?

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics

I feel like it should be obvious, but I've had a mental block about this because I don't remember it being explicitly said. I've seen it in text books where the current arrow (i1, i2, is, etc.) has been in front of the resistor and in other places it would be after the resistor. Does it make a difference when making further calculations?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. If the circuit splits into 2 current paths, THEN it matters which path the arrow is on...

Comment: Resistors (and other circuit elements) cannot store charge. One of the most basic ideas of circuit analysis is that if you draw a box around a component and add up all the currents flowing into the box, they must sum to zero. So for every charge that enters via terminal one, another must exit through terminal two. Instantaneously and always. So, no, it doesn't matter where you put the arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdsOp1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Current flowing around a circuit. The current in the example is calculated using Ohm's law, \$ V = IR \$.*

You can think of electrical current as being like a bicycle chain of charge moving around a circuit.

- The same amount of chain passes through every point simultaneously. (Our example has no branches.)
- What leaves the power supply on the positive terminal returns to the negative.

Therefore, it doesn't matter where the arrow is placed.

When we introduce parallel branches into the circuit we need to treat each loop separately but the same principle applies in each loop.

Please request clarification, if required.

Answer (score 1):

This is much better suited for the electronics SE site than the puzzling one, but that being said -- if I understand your question correctly, it doesn't matter.

A resistor has two identical terminals; current that comes in one side must exit the other, so the current magnitude and direction at each terminal must always be the same.